# What column is this alias referring to?

Tags: oracle, join, syntax

I've read the following code a few times trying to figure out what it is doing.

> "A right outer join is that which returns the unmatched rows from the right tables with matched rows from the left table."

Ok, but the column `"item_cnt"` does not exist in the tables, then what column is it serving as an alias? I'm preparing for 1z0-047 so any help would be appreciated.

---

You executed the following query to display `PRODUCT_NAME` and the number of times the product has been ordered:

```
SELECT p.product_name, i.item_cnt
FROM (SELECT product_id, COUNT (*) item_cnt
FROM order_items
GROUP BY product_id) i RIGHT OUTER JOIN products p ON i.product_id = p.product_id;
```

---

I thought that the column should exist. But here is the Oracle docs page with all example schemas. If I search with ctrl+f for `item_cnt`, I find nothing: [Oracle example schemas](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28328/scripts.htm#).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Ok, but the column `"item_cnt"` does not exist in the tables, then what column is it serving as an alias?

The column `item_cnt` may not exist in the **base tables** (we believe you, we didn't go and search the linked documents.)

But this part of the code:

```
FROM 
     (SELECT product_id, COUNT (*) item_cnt
      FROM order_items
      GROUP BY product_id) i
```

provides a **derived table**. The column exists during the time that the query runs, in the derived table `i`. The `(SELECT product_id, ... item_cnt ...) AS i` defines a derived table, it names it `i` and this derived table has two columns, `product_id` and `item_cnt` (and `item_cnt` is an alias for the expression `COUNT(*)`. There is no count(*) column either in any of the tables!)

So, later in the code, you can use them. The `i.product_id` is used in the `ON` condition and the `i.item_cnt` in the `SELECT` list.

(And it's a bit confusing that it seems to appear earlier and not later. That's because the `SELECT` part of a query is logically executed after the `FROM` part.)

```
FROM (...) i RIGHT OUTER JOIN products p ON ...
```

For the query execution, the two tables (aliased `i` and `p`) have no difference. It doesn't matter that one is a **base table** and the other a **derived table**. They can be used the same way. (and as far as we know, the `products` may not be a base table either. It can very well be a **viewed table**, usually referred as a **view**.)

Comment: Thanks again @ypercube! I'm lucky there aren't interest rates applied for very delayed "checked as correct answers" on stack exchange hehe. Thanks.